# Having a Error approval column not found in the System.log

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6, system.log

I having this below error on the system.log continuously.

> main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'approval' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2) AS `min_price_expr` FROM `catalog_product_index_price` AS `e`
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store2` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=2 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='1961'
>    INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1
>    INNER JOIN `search_tmp_5cd177f4280396_75007589` AS `search_result` ON e.entity_id = search_result.entity_id WHERE (stock_status_index.stock_status = 1) AND (approval IN (2, 4)) AND (vendor_id NOT IN(142,147,148,149,150,151,152,154,157,159,161,162,163)) AND ( e.website_id = '1' ) AND ( e.customer_group_id = 0) AND (e.min_price IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY `e`.`min_price` ASC
>    LIMIT 10000000000 [] []

I don't have any idea with this error. anyone can help me to clear this error is highly Appreciated.

Comment: Please enable the server to display error.

Comment: @ManishGoswami  enable the server means ?